# List getting cleared before AsyncTask completes

Tags: android, twitter, android-listview

I have an AsyncTask which loads Tweets from Twitter.
I also have a PullToRefresh ListView... Whenever i pull to refresh it, the listview immediately clears and as soon as the data has been loaded, it's getting filled into the listview.

I have other ListViews in my App all with the same stuff (PullToRefresh and Async data loading...). On the other ListViews this does not happen. Only on the Twitter ListView. What am I doing wrong?

Here is my Code:

```
    public class TwitterDownloader extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {

    final Handler mHandler = new Handler();

    public TwitterDownloader() {
    }

    @Override
    public void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
        twitter4j.Twitter twitter = new TwitterFactory().getInstance();

        listTweets.clear();

            List<twitter4j.Status> statuses = null;

            try {
                statuses = twitter.getUserTimeline(
                        MainActivity.TWITTER_USERNAME, new Paging(1, 50));
            } catch (TwitterException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Log.e(MainActivity.LOG_TAG, "TwitterException");
            }

            try {
                for (twitter4j.Status status : statuses) {
                    listTweets.add(status.getText());
                }
            } catch (NullPointerException npe) {
            }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onPostExecute(String unused) {
        MyCustomAdapter myAdapter = new MyCustomAdapter(myContext,
                R.layout.row_twitter, listTweets);
        setListAdapter(myAdapter);
        getListView().setTextFilterEnabled(true);

        String lastUpdate = (new SimpleDateFormat(
                "HH:mm")).format(new Date());

        pullToRefreshView.onRefreshComplete();
        pullToRefreshView.setLastUpdatedLabel(getString(R.string.last_updated) + ": "
                + lastUpdate);
    }
```

Comment: How exactly would I do that? Where would I have to add it? And how exactly?

Comment: put myAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged() into onPostExcute(); If it doesn't work, show your logcat (should print stack trace of NullPointerException )

Comment: Do I need to do it before I call setListAdapter or after?
Because now I removed the clear() statement just as Basavaraj told me to but now the data is still the old one after refreshing...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally fixed it by adding all my clear() statements right before I fill up my list again (which is inside a try catch).

So the new code inside my doInBackground method is:

```
try {
            listTweets.clear();
            listUsernames.clear();
            listDates.clear();
            listImageURLs.clear();
            listURLsOfTweets.clear();
            for (twitter4j.Status status : statuses) {
                listTweets.add(status.getText());
                listUsernames.add(status.getUser().getName());
                listDates.add(android.text.format.DateFormat
                        .getDateFormat(getApplicationContext()).format(
                                status.getCreatedAt())
                        + " "
                        + android.text.format.DateFormat.getTimeFormat(
                                getApplicationContext()).format(
                                status.getCreatedAt()));
                listImageURLs.add(status.getUser().getProfileImageURL()
                        .toString());

                StringBuffer address = new StringBuffer();
                address.append("http://twitter.com/#!/");
                address.append(status.getUser().getScreenName());
                address.append("/status/");
                address.append(status.getId());

                listURLsOfTweets.add(address.toString());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure about this but in `doInBackground` method of AsyncTask, you are doing `listTweets.clear();`. After getting result, you are adding data to it. May be this is causing problems.

Comment: Well that shouldn't be bad since it's the first call in doInBackground no?

Comment: I'm wondering a bit, because normally you are not allowed to modify the UI of the activity from the doInBackground() method, as it runs in a separate thread. Check the LogCat if the listTwitts.clear() does not throw an exception.

Comment: Wow looks like removing it did the Job! Thanks alot!

Comment: @user754730 - yes that shouldn't be a problem but 1 more thing i observed is that in onPostExecute() method you are setting adapter again before refreshing. Check that... may thats the problem.

Comment: @AndyRes - of course we are not allowed to do UI modifications in background thread(in doInBackground method especially) but in this case there is no UI modification is done in doInBackground. Right?

Comment: @Basavaraj, I assumed listTweets.clear() clears the ListView, and ListView is a UI component.

Comment: @Basavaraj What do you mean with I set adapter before refreshing? Would do I need to change?

Comment: @user754730 - If its working as expected, then no need to change.

Comment: @Basavaraj Well now the refreshing works correctly... But the data is still the old data from before...

Comment: @user754730 - I think that listTweets is a global array. So, every time you set adapter, its taking all previous and current items. I am not sure about it but check it for yourself once.

Comment: private ArrayList<String> listTweets = new ArrayList<String>();

This is my decleration. So I was not right clearing it before filling it with new entries?

Comment: @user754730 - May be. Just make sure that before setting adapter, whatever data you pass to MyCustomAdapter should be new data not the mixture of old and new data.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/14951/discussion-between-user754730-and-basavaraj)

Comment: I have not heared anything since then. Can anyone help?